# Change MaterialDesignin TextBox style color

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, material-design

So i have this `MaterialDesignin` `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Width="300" 
         materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="User name"
         materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True"/>
```

Result without focus:

[image]

Result with focus:

[image]

My `app.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Red.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

So i want to chanhe the `TextBox` color for the first picture (without focus) to be something else, i try to change the `Foreground property` but this not works.
I mean to change this `Gray` line color (the red color while focus i want).

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever you want as a hint.

```
<TextBox>
    <materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red">User name</TextBlock>
    </materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint>
</TextBox>
```

If you want to apply a common style to all your hints, it might be better to use a style for the `SmartHint` control, based on the default one.

```
<Style TargetType="materialDesign:SmartHint" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:SmartHint}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```